# Windows Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to understand windows azure SQL database functionality and it leads to some questions that I am looking to be clarified.

1. What we can do to get full SQL Server functionality in windows azure application
2. How to store large amount of unstructured data in windows azure
3. What quality every entity in windows azure table should posses i.e. Partion Key, Row Key etc.

Comment: 1- What specific things are you looking for. If it's not there in SQL Azure its not there. 2 - What type of data? 3- Only two properties are mandatory PartitionKey and RowKey.

Comment: 1) I want to know what I need to do for this i.e. a)By using SQL Database I can do this or b)By leveraging windows azure table storage I can achieve it or anything etc.                                              2) Either use Windows azure table or window azure blobs etc.

Comment: Oh,sorry 1 - SQL Azure and SQL Server are similar when consumed from client app, so you can use it without any issues 2- Tables are for objects, azure blob for files

Comment: @Chandermani - Please post answers as *answers* and not as comments. Further: Your *answer* is not accurate concerning Windows Azure SQL Database (formerly known as SQL Azure).

Comment: @AshishKhandelwal - you should separate these into three separate questions, as they each have an independent answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon point noted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read these:

[Windows Azure Table Storage and Windows Azure SQL Database - Compared and Contrasted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj553018.aspx)

[Guidelines and Limitations (Windows Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394102.aspx)